# Direction when fading out element with hide()

Tags: jquery, hide, direction

I'm using the code shown in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BADfT/651/) to remove a div with the effect provided by hide(). I'm trying to make the div fading out to its top-right corner instead of the top-left but couldn't get it to work even when specifying `direction:'right'` in the options.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hide function you currently use is an extension included in the jQuery UI.
This function calls internally the animate function (refer to [jQuery UI hide)](https://jqueryui.com/hide/).

In order to obtain the effect you are looking for here is the snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide('size', {
      to: {
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        marginLeft: parseInt($(this).css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? $(this).outerWidth() : 0
      }
    },
                 function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #3b85c3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Using, instead, the standard [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function here is the corresponding snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
      height: 'toggle',
      width: 'toggle',
      marginLeft: parseInt($(this).css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ? $(this).outerWidth() : 0
    }, function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #3b85c3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the `size` effect for JQuery UI's `.hide()` method, you could use the `origin` option, rather than the `to` option. That is, you could use `{ origin: ['top', 'right'] }` for the `options` argument. [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/n3k4kzfc/)